# Example from pandas rename documentation doesn't work on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to replicate the example from the [pandas rename documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html).

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s.rename("test")
```

Which throws the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<stdin>", line 1, in
<module>   File
"/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2264,
in rename
    return super(Series, self).rename(index=index, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 606,
in rename
    result._data = result._data.rename_axis(f, axis=baxis, copy=copy)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line
2588, in rename_axis
    obj.set_axis(axis, _transform_index(self.axes[axis], mapper))   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line
4391, in _transform_index
    items = [func(x) for x in index] TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I'm running Ubuntu  16.04.1. I noticed the references to python2.7, so I made sure I've downloaded the most recent pandas and python versions.

Why is such a simple function from the documentation throwing an error?

Comment: What is the output of `pd.__version__`?

Comment: My current pandas version is 0.17.1

Comment: Updating to pandas 0.19.1 did not fix it.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.1/whatsnew.html#changes-to-rename Series.rename started to change axis name in version 0.18.0.

Comment: Have you restarted the kernel?

Comment: When I forcefully check my python version using import sys, print(sys.version), it says that I'm running 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10). When I force python3.5 from the command line, it can't find pandas. How do I tie all of this together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is troubling when things don't work as advertised! Maybe that signals something important for you to track down, because it might signal other problems or incompatibilities.  But if you're needing this particular thing to work, there is a simple workaround:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
s.name = 'test'
```

`rename` is a bit of an octopus method, doing different things depending on the input (renaming the whole series, renaming index values, ...). The "rename the Series" invocation, however, can be very directly restated by assigning to its `name` property.

Note the comments: What actually worked was not naming the `Series`, but assigning to the `DataFrame`:

```
df['test'] = s
```

Also, it appears from another post that a thorough roto-tilling of the installation was another successful approach.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for my ultimate purpose, which is to concatenate the Series as a column to an existing dataframe *with a unique column name*. The .name workaround preserved the original series name for some reason.

Comment: And `df['test'] = s` didn't add the `Series` to the `DataFrame` with the `'test'` name you have chosen? That is a more direct route to adding columns than changing names of `Series`, which are usually anonymous.

Comment: That works ;-) I'm a python newbie, so half the point of these workarounds is to fail my way to success. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The version difficulties were caused by my misunderstanding of how Ubuntu runs versions of python. Where everyone uses "pip", it meant "pip3" for my situation and "python" means "python3".

The following steps on Ubuntu resolved my issue.

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo -H pip3 install pandas
```

Upon launching, I need to launch with *python3* instead of *python*.

```
python3
import pandas as pd #no errors!
```